# LibGdx Cutting Texture Instead of Scaling It

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

When I draw the sprite at (0,0) with the texture's original size (256,256) it works fine, but when I change the position or the size, the sprite is being messed up.
Here is the code:

```
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Sprite sprite;
private OrthographicCamera camera;

@Override
public void create () {
    camera=new OrthographicCamera(600,600);
    camera.position.set(0,0,0);
    camera.update();
    batch=new SpriteBatch();
    sprite=new Sprite(new Texture("TestBlock_01.png"),0,0,256,256);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.draw(sprite,sprite.getX(),sprite.getY(),sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());
    batch.end();
}
```

resault:
[image]

But now when I change the position and the size to (-100,-100,100,100):
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `sprite.draw(batch);`, not `batch.draw(sprite, ...);`. You could call it a fundamental design issue of libgdx to have Sprite extend TextureRegion and hopefully it will be fixed in a next major version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to replace

```
sprite=new Sprite(Texture,x,y,width,height);
```

with

```
sprite=new Sprite(Texture);
sprite.setPosition(x,y);
sprite.setSize(width height);
```

Comment: Splitting the constructor has no effect accutally

Comment: the constructor changes the srcX,srcY,srcWidth and srcHeight variables.
these are different variables from the normal x,y,width,height.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the sprite origin to work perfectly along with scale and position changing.As described [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html)

```
void    setOrigin(float originX, float originY)
Sets the origin in relation to the sprite's position for scaling and rotation.
```

And also call the draw method in render with parameter originX, OriginY if you need to rotate perfectly. As described [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html)

```
void    draw(TextureRegion region, float x, float y, float originX, float originY, float width, float height, float scaleX, float scaleY, float rotation)

Draws a rectangle with the bottom left corner at x,y and stretching the region to cover the given width and height.
```